# Increase WPF GridSplitter mouse grabbing threshold

Tags: wpf, gridsplitter

Is it possible to increase the distance from a grid splitter from which the user can grab it?

My splitter is only 1px in width. I would like to be able to grab the splitter from a greater distance.

As it is now i must point the mouse on the exact 1px line to grab it.

And the splitter must still be 1px in width

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can change the actual size of the `GridSplitter` while keeping it looking like it's smaller. This will give you a 7 pixel width area to grab it while showing at 1 pixel:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"
                  Margin="-3,0"
                  BorderThickness="3,0"
                  BorderBrush="Transparent"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

The example is using the method of giving the splitter its own column but the same principle applies if it's Left or Right aligned in a shared column.

Comment: This is correct, but i had to change the ZIndex of the gridsplitter, because it right hand side got hidden by a DockPanel.

Comment: What is the purpose of Margin="-3,0"?  You want the horizontal splitter left aligned in the 7 pixel area instead of centered?

Comment: The negative Margins create the extra space on either side for the 3 px transparent border to fill in the layout. Without those the splitter only has the 1 px column to render in.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `BorderBrush="Transparent"` is key. If you leave it as the default (`No brush`) then this doesn't work.

Comment: To clarify @ErikTJ's comment: You need to place the GridSplitter **after** the other elements in the grid (lower in the source code), so it will not be covered by them.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an ancient question but I thought I would add my answer anyway.  After a lot of experimenting the following seems to work perfectly for a 1 pixel wide `Gridsplitter`

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="gs0" TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
    <Border Margin="-5,0" Background="Transparent">
        <TextBlock Width="1"  Background="Green" />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Tested with the following code:

```
Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"  >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Grid Grid.Column="0">
    ....
</Grid>

<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Template ="{StaticResource gs0}"/>
```

Without the template, the "mouse grabbing area" is 1 pixel.  But set as above with the template, it is increased to 7 pixels which is about right.  The same code can be adjusted for a 2 or more pixel width line, by tweaking the `Textblock`  `Width`, `Border Margin` and `ColumnDefinition Width`.  You can make the mouse grab ridiculously huge but the problem is that the increase is only on the left side; it's not centred on the line, which becomes more noticeable the more you increase it.  But for a narrow line, it's an easy way to increase the mouse grab to something useable.

I'm using 2 pixel wide `Gridsplitters` and use a style to set `IsMouseOver` properties and such:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
    <Setter Property="OpacityMask" Value="{StaticResource gs_OpacityMask}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
                <Border Margin="-3,0" Background="Transparent">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tb" Width="2"  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="tb" Value="#FF0B75FD" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

IMPORTANT: The `ColumnDefinition Width` needs to be set to 3 or 4 in this case of a 2 pixel width line.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to get John Bowen's solution to work.  It looked like it worked, but it seemed like the splitter only had 1 pixel of grab space.

I ended up doing this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Stackpanel Grid.Row="0"/>
    <GridSplitter
        Grid.Row="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        BorderBrush="DarkGray"
        Height="6"
        Background="Transparent"
        BorderThickness="0,1,0,0"
        Margin="0,0,0,-4"/>
    <Stackpanel Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

This gives the splitter 6 pixels of height, but shows only the 1 pixel top border line.  You use a negative bottom margin of ((Height / 2) - 1) in order to center that top margin line in the middle of the row.

The Background is Transparent otherwise you will see 6 pixels of gray or w/e the default color is.  If you dig into the control template for GridSplitter with Blend you find out it's just a styled Rectangle with a Border or something like that.

Comment: The problem with this technique is it puts the grey line at the top of the 6 pixel area where you can grab the grey line.  Are you sure you didn't simply forget to flip some values in your translation of John's answer from vertical to horizontal?  This worked for me (5 pixel area to grab, grey line in center of area): `<GridSplitter Height="5" BorderThickness="0,2" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />`